# Easiest way to solve this system of equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I have these two equations:

$$x=\frac{ab(1+k)}{b+ka}\\ y=\frac{ab(1+k)}{a+kb}$$

where $a,b$ are constants and $k$ is a parameter to be eliminated.

A relation between $x,y$ is to be found. What is the best way to do it? Cross multiplying and solving is a bit too hectic. Is there a way we can maybe exploit the symmetry of the situation? Thanks!!

Comment: Don't know if this helps but $\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} = \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b}$

Comment: @iamwhoiam. Is that easy to see? Oh yeah. That's easy. I think you should make that an answer.

Comment: I think it is, since the the numerator of $x$ and $y$ is the same. So it kinda makes sense that you might take a closer look on $x^{-1}$ and $y^{-1}$.

Comment: @iamwhoiam This was what I was looking for!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @iamwhoiam I think you should post it as an answer!

Comment: Added it as an answer

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Notice that the numerators of the two fractions are equal. It might thus be helpful to consider $\frac{1}{x}$ and $\frac{1}{y}$. With this approach, we observe that $$\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} = \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b}$$

Comment: Nicely done (+1).

Comment: What step am I missing to get to $\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} $?$\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} = \frac{a + ak + b + kb}{ab(1 + k)} \iff \frac{a (1 + k) + b (1 + k)}{ab(1 + k)} \iff \frac{(a + b) (1 + k)}{ab(1 + k)} \iff \frac{(a + b)}{ab} \iff ???$

Comment: @PhilPatterson $\frac{(a+b)}{ab}$ <-> $\frac{a}{ab} + \frac{b}{ab}$ <-> $\frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{a}$ <-> $\frac1a+\frac1b$

Comment: @pizzapants184 somehow I forgot that you could split the terms in that way ... amazing how much you can forget 15 years after university ... Thanks for spelling it out for me!

Comment: @ $P^2$. Why do we hate $=$ signs?

Comment: This was literally the first time in my life using MathJax to create equations ... now that you've said something about it @Mason, I have to assume those double arrows have another meaning and I just used them erroneously. Reflecting on it I picked them because I liked the way they looked ... FWIW

Answer (score 16):

Direct elimination doesn't look so hectic in this case:

$$(b+ka)x=ab(1+k) \iff ka(x-b)=b(a-x)\iff k = - \frac{b(x-a)}{a(x-b)}$$

Doing the same for the second equation then equating eliminates $\,k\,$.

Comment: Thanks! But I think that adding $x^-1$ and $y^-1$ and adding them (as mentioned in the comments) is a nice trick here ;-)

Comment: @tatan I agree, and will upvote that once posted as an answer ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, note that $$\frac xy=\frac{a+kb}{b+ka}\implies (bx-ay)=k(by-ax)\implies k=\frac{bx-ay}{by-ax}$$ and equate with @dxiv's answer.